# Applicability of a $1$-form picking just one vector in the cotanget space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

One of the definitions of a $1$-form is that it is a vectorfield  picking a covector for each point. Or in other words picking one member of the cotangent space at some point, in the same way a vector field is a pick from the tangent space.

Presumably the 1 forms is something we use to study differentail equations, which in turn are related to picking a vector of the tangent space.

I am puzzled how we are suppose to use the $1$-forms to study the equations, we usually have $ 1$ vector from the tangent space given an equation. But to "get info" on this vector it seams we want more then just $1 $ covector or equivalently $ 1$ functional on the tangent space.

Does someone understand what I don't understand?

Comment: Where have to seen this definition?

Comment: @BenCWBrown 
 http://www.physicsinsights.org/pbp_one_forms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-form defines a hyperplane, a co-dimension 1 subspace, in the tangent space. If your space is the euclidean plane, then these subspaces resp. their projection from the tangent space to the point space are lines. Thus a one-form in a plane defines a direction field. No orientation or length of vector is fixed. However, if you select them, with having quite the freedom in this, you get a vector field on which you then can solve a differential equation.

Comment: I can see how a one form defines a direction field. Ca you elaborate on the last two sentences?

Comment: If you have a one-form $Mdx+Ndy$, you can select as vector field $F(x,y)=(N,-M)$ or divide this by $\sqrt{1+M^2+N^2}$ or multiply with any other factor to get a different vector field. The solutions of $(\dot x,\dot y)=F(x,y)$ for these different $F$ share the same curves (as point-sets), but with different parametrizations.

Comment: OK, hence we dont use the one-forms to study or measure vectors? It just looks like we use them to get a new formulation of the equation.

Comment: The use is the progression to integrating factors and first integrals, which is slightly easier to formulate starting from the one-forms. And notice that the relevant vector field is in the null-space of the one-form, no use for measuring it.

Comment: Ok, ill  have to look into that. Thanks. By the way measuring to be zero could be considered to be measuring right? Odd that the 1 forms are explianed as measuing divices in that case.

Comment: Also by "selecting them" you mean make a choice from the cotanget space at each point? I.e specifying the 1-form/direction field.

Comment: Yes, but usually one demands at least continuity, if not differentiability, of the selected vector field.